# How can a capacitor discharge if there is no field outside?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-fields

On RC circuit, capacitor discharges when the voltage supply is removed.

But I've learned that the net electric field outside a charged capacitor is zero by gaussian surface and gauss law.

I don't understand the mechanism. Shouldn't be there an electric field in order to make charge flow when discharging happens?

Is there an another mechanism?

Comment: *"But I've learned that the net electric field outside a charged capacitor is zero by gaussian surface and gauss law."* - the fact that there is no net charge enclosed within the volume enclosed by the surface doesn't imply that there's zero electric field outside of that volume does it? Consider the electric field of a [simple electric dipole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole#Field_from_an_electric_dipole).

Comment: @alfred  Thanks for the reply. I've figured it out with your help. I was confused with  infinite sheet of charge case

Comment: @AlfredCentauri What you say makes sense since there is a difference  between the NET flux across the surface being zero and there being no flux across the surface. But many answers on this site state there is no electric field outside a charged capacitor and they don't seem to make the distinction between flux and net flux.Your thoughts?

Comment: @BobD, I don't know why that would be unless they explicitly state something like "ignoring the fringing fields". If I recall correctly, I've engaged someone here (or maybe Wikipedia) before regarding the fringing fields and the fact that they are crucial for understanding and explaining some capacitor problems, i.e., you *can't* ignore fringing fields except for when, e.g., approximating the capacitance of a capacitor.

Comment: user265256, I found this slide that you may find helpful:  [How is Discharging Possible?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ypwf.png)

Comment: @AlfredCentauri I recall it being said there is  no electric field outside the capacitor EXCEPT for that due to the fringe fields. I didn't think you said the electric field is due to fringe effects. A Gaussian surface enclosing an electric dipole is a clear example of net flux being zero, but field not being zero. But this link from Hyperphysics shows no field outside the capacitor(?):http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elesht.html#c2

Comment: @BobD, at the link in your comment, the first sentence begins: *"If oppositely charges [sic] parallel conducting plates are treated like infinite planes (neglecting fringing),"* so I'm not sure what you're getting at, but I am sure it's off-topic in this comment thread. I would ask if you wanted to move to chat but I don't see that option available.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Yes I know what it says. And it shows no field outside the capacitor, so I guess you are saying if there is no fringing then there is no field outside the capacitor. Anyway, that's OK we can leave it at that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108345/discussion-between-alfred-centauri-and-bob-d).

Answer (score 1):

> But I've learned that the net electric field outside a charged
>   capacitor is zero by gaussian surface and gauss law.

First, Gauss's law states that the electric *flux* through a closed surface enclosing a volume with zero net electric charge is zero. That does not imply that the electric field outside the volume is zero, it implies that every electric field line that originates (terminates) in the volume also terminates (originates) in the volume (even if part of the field line is outside the volume).

Here's a 'picture' of the electric field of a charged capacitor that I found at the answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/297177/9887):

[image]

The *fringing field* is often ignored in elementary capacitor calculations but it must not be ignored if one is to fully explain capacitor operation.

Also, there is essentially a duplicate of your question here:  [Why does a capacitor discharge?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60154/9887)

I've answered your post here just to clear up the misconception you have regarding Gauss's law.

Comment: Again, Thank you for your kind answer. I have understood the concepts I asked correctly with your help. I'm sad that I can't express how I am grateful of you because I'm not that good at writing english...

Answer (score -1):

it is only discharged. if the two plates are connected by some resistor. otherwise it stays charged.

Comment: trula, I've downvoted your answer because it is more of a comment and not an answer (it doesn't actually address what I believe to be the OP's question).